# Must declare the scalar variable "@soNum". One method works, the other doesn't

Tags: c#, sql-server

This one works:

```
private void LogOpen()
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", userPrincipal.Name);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opened", DateTime.Now);

    string sqlString = "INSERT INTO [Automation].[dbo].[WDAutomationUsage] ([Name], [Opened]) " +
                       "OUTPUT INSERTED.ID " +
                       "VALUES (@Name, @Opened)";

    sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlString;

    if (diagramBuilder.sqlConn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        diagramBuilder.sqlConn.Open();
    }

    sqlCommand.Connection = diagramBuilder.sqlConn;
    usageID = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

This one does not:

```
private void LogSONumber(string soNum)
{
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsageID", usageID);
        //sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONumber", soNum);
        SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@SONumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        sqlParameter.Value = soNum;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

        string sqlString = "INSERT INTO [Automation].[dbo].[WDAutomationSONums] ([UsageID], [SONumber]) " +
                           "OUTPUT INSERTED.ID " +
                           "VALUES (@usageID, @soNum)";

        sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlString;

        if (diagramBuilder.sqlConn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            diagramBuilder.sqlConn.Open();
        }

        sqlCommand.Connection = diagramBuilder.sqlConn;
        usageSOID = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
    }
```

In the second one, I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@soNum"

As you can see, I've tried two different ways of declaring soNum but I still get the same error. Please help, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: You're declaring a "SONumber" variable, while using a "soNum" parameter in your query... please align names

Comment: You pass in `@SONumber`, but it expects `@soNum`.

Comment: Be **very careful** using AddWithValue, it can do some really interesting things. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ Far better to be explicit and state the datatype you want to use.

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange. Fortunately I haven't done this enough to make it a habit so it shouldn't be too hard to change. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply using a different variable identifier in your `INSERT` than what you are passing as the `SqlParameter`.

Change `VALUES (@usageID, @soNum)` to `VALUES (@usageID, @SONumber)`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Lews Therin, LittleSweetSeas, and Peter B!